# Why does the equal to operator not work if it is not surrounded by spaces?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, scripting

I tried the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1="Test 1" 
var2="Test 2"
if [ "$var1"="$var2" ] 
  then 
    echo "Equal" 
  else 
    echo "Not equal"
fi
```

It gave me `Equal`. Although it should have printed `Not equal`

Only when I inserted space around `=` it worked as intended:

```
if [ "$var1" = "$var2" ]
```

and printed `Not equal`

Why is it so? Why is `"$var1"="$var2"` not same as `"$var1" = "$var2"`?

Moreover, when I wrote `if [ "$var1"= "$var2" ]`, it gave

```
line 4: [: Test 1=: unary operator expected
```

What does it mean? How come it's expecting a unary operator?

Comment: If you do a `test STRING` or (equivalently `[ STRING ]`),  this always evaluates to true (see _man test_).  `"$var1"="$var2"` is obviously a single string, while `"$var1" = "$var2" ` are three arguments, in which case the middle argument is taken as operator. When you do a `[ "$var1"= "$var2" ]`, you are passing two arguments, and in this case, the first argument must be an unary operator - for instance `-n`. This is also explained in _man test_.

Comment: Your title is misleading. There is not even an attempt to do a regex matching in your code. The bash regex operator is `=~`, and is available inside a `[[ ... ]]` construct.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`test` (or `[ expr ]`) is a builtin function. Like all functions in bash, you pass its arguments as whitespace separated words.

As the man page for bash builtins states: "Each operator and operand must be a separate argument."

It's just the way bash and most other Unix shells work.

Variable assignment is different.

In bash a variable assignment has the syntax: `name=[value]`. You cannot put unquoted spaces around the `=` because bash would not interpret this as the assignment you intend. bash treats most lists of words as a command with parameters.

E.g.

```
# call the command or function 'abc' with '=def' as argument
abc =def

# call 'def' with the variable 'abc' set to the empty string
abc= def

# call 'ghi' with 'abc' set to 'def'
abc=def ghi

# set 'abc' to 'def ghi'
abc="def ghi"
```

Comment: Thanks Charles Bailey. There is one thing more, as man page says "each operator and ...." then why `var = "test" ;` does not work? To make it work, I have to remove spaces `var="test";` Is assignment `=` is not an operator?

Comment: That man page applies to the `test` builtin function. In bash a variable assignment is part of the shell grammar, it's not a function. It requires no spaces.

Comment: ...and 'abc = def' invokes the command abc with two arguments '=' and 'def'

Answer (score 8):

When the shell reads

```
if [ "$var1" = "$var2" ]
```

it invokes the command [ with 4 arguments.  Whether [ is a builtin or an external command is irrelevant, but it may help to understand that it may be the external command /bin/[.  The second argument is the literal '=' and the fourth is ']'.  However, when the shell reads

```
if [ "$var1"= "$var2" ]
```

[ only gets 3 arguments: the expansion of $var1 with '=' appended, the expansion of $var2, and ']'.  When it gets only 3 arguments, it expects the last argument to be ']' and the first argument to be a unary operator.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the existing explanation, `"$var1"="$var2"` is just a single non-empty string, and thus always evaluates as true in a conditional.

```
[ "$var1"="$var2" ] && echo true
```

The above command will always print out `true` (even if `var1` and `var2` be empty).

Answer (score -2):

In bash the best is to use [[ ]]:

```
x="test"
y="test"
if [[ "${x}" = "${y}" ]]; then
    echo "Equals"
else
    echo "No equals"
fi
```

Comment: Bash`[[` is governed by the same shell syntax as all other constructs. Switching to `[[` would not  solve the OP's problem. As to whether this is "better" depends on whether you prioritize convenience over portability. If you are committed to Bash-only, it's probably true.

Comment: As I wrote, I meant **bash**. Of course if you want your code to be portable, you should use **/bin/sh**

Comment: Still, this does not attempt to address the OP's question, and should be posted as a  comment instead (if at all).

Comment: @knesenko you should read better both questions and comments...