# bash scripting if-else simple issue

Tags: linux, bash

Dude, so sorry about the absolute noob question.
What is the problem with the following code?
I like to have a simple script which says MEH! when there is no input arg, otherwise prints it.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [${#$1}==0] then
echo "MEH!";
else
echo $1;
fi
```

OS says the line 4 has a error (unexpected token else at line 4).
So sorry dude.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `if [${#$1}==0] then` use `if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then`

Comment: FYI, this is covered on http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: Please read the `bash` man page. It is quite clear about where whitespace is required and where it is forbidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably wanted to use:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ${#1} -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "MEH!";
else
   echo $1
fi
```

Problems in your current `if [${#$1}==0] then` condition:

- spaces around `[` and `]` are needed. For further information, you can check the excellent answer by Charles Bailey in [Why equal to operator does not work if its not surrounded by space?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4977390/1983854).
- `==` is used on string comparison. In this case you want integer comparison, that is `-eq`. See [Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) in the manual for a full list of them.

---

In general, if you want to check if your script is receiving at least a parameter, you'd better do:

```
if [ $# -ge 1 ]; then
   echo "$# parameters given"
else
   echo "no parameters given"
fi
```

or also, [as commented by Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192148/bash-scripting-if-else-simple-issue/25192187?noredirect=1#comment39230193_25192187):

```
if [ -z "$1" ]   # true if the variable $1 has length 0
```

Last and not least: check the comments below, as good information was provided.

Comment: Perfect dear, works like charm, now except Java, bash would walk on my nerve too :D, thanks.

Comment: is there any other better way(correct way) to find out if any argument is  provided or not except '${#1}' approach?

Comment: ...well, in baseline POSIX `[ ]` as opposed to `[[ ]]`, `==` isn't valid string comparison either; it's just that many shells support it as an extension. Better to use `=`, though.

Comment: @user2889419, if your script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, `(( $# > 0 ))` to tell if it's more than zero arguments, or `[[ $1 ]]` to check if the first argument is non-empty. What do you want to do if it's explicitly provided, but empty? To provide a concrete example: if someone runs `your_script ""`, the argument exists, but is an empty string.

Comment: @user2889419, ...in baseline POSIX sh, `[ ${#1} -eq 0 ]` is better written as `[ -z "$1" ]`.

Comment: @user2889419 yes, moreover to what Charles Duffy suggest you can also use `[ $# -ge 1 ]`.

Comment: The problem with `[ ${#1} -eq 0 ]` occurs when the shell is invoked **without** any arguments. In that case the positional parameter 1 is not defined. While the length of an undefined variable defaults to `0`, this isn't the recommended way to test -- it is a hack.