# Passing npm description to npm script command

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, npm

I'm trying to pass the description from my package.json file up to AWS. The package description is a string like so:

```
"description": "A simple hello world from my web app",
```

And the npm script calls the aws command line and needs a description for the Lambda function:

```
"scripts": {
  "create": "aws lambda create-function --function-name $npm_package_name --description $npm_package_description
}
```

But `$npm_package_description` ends up becoming multiple parameters in the aws call. How do I pass the result of $npm_package_description as a string?

This is the error I get, by the way:

`Unknown options: A, simple, hello, world, from, my, web, app`

Answer (score 1):

Tried something random and it worked.

Wrapping `'$npm_package_description'` in single quotes didn't help, it just stayed a string, but apparently escaped double quotes worked.

Like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "create": "aws lambda create-function --function-name $npm_package_name --description \"$npm_package_description\"
}
```

Can anyone explain why this works?

Comment: It's because of _Word spitting_ as per @msanford comment. By placing the `$npm_package_description` variable in double quotes you prevent word splitting, and because it's JSON that's why you have to escape the double quotes. i.e. `\"...\"`.

Comment: @Costa Because [single quotes do not trigger _parameter expansion_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802438/114900), meaning anything within them is treated literally. Try a little test in a bash console: `read a` and enter `Hello World` (and hit enter). Then execute `$a`, and `'$a'` and `"$a"` individually and observe the errors. `'$a'` will complain that the literal string `$a` is not found, whereas `"$a"` will complain that `"Hello"` is not found (the expanded parameter).

Comment: Single quotes remove the special meaning of all characters between the quotes, in your case that means the reference to `$npm_package_description` (i.e. the dollar `$`) is ignored. This results in all chars inside single quotes becoming a literal string. However, when using Double quotes  every substitution beginning with a dollar sign `$` is performed. More info [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Types_of_quoting).

Comment: I'll offer a generalization: bash-like scripting is intricate and unforgiving, in favour of being extremely terse.  So, while many languages treat `"` and `'` as the same thing (or, [for that matter, `a=1` and `a = 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4977390/114900)), bash does not. This can lead to much unexpected behaviour when coming from another language.

Comment: @Costa Check out Greg's blog above, excellent resource. Then, put scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net) (past contributor) and read through tags on [unix.se]. Have fun! Once you get the hang of it, it's actually extremely powerful, and a great tool in the belt.

Comment: Also, accept your own answer: it was the correct one, after all! You can flag this comment as "No Longer Necessary" once you have, if you like.