# Read a file and show the lines present in the file which do start with a certain sub-string

Tags: string, bash, shell

I am a beginner in shell scripting.
I am trying to write a shell script which reads a file   and prints out the lines in the file that starts with and ends with a certain word - say "Hi" in my case..
So I wrote he script to find the lines which starts with "Hi" , but got an error..Any help what is the problem?

```
    f="\bkg\inp.txt"
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

        if [[ $line=="Hi*"]]; then
            printf '%s\n' "$line"
        fi

    done < "$f"
```

The error says:

```
$ sh script.sh
script.sh: line 5: unexpected token `;', conditional binary operator expected
script.sh: line 5: syntax error near `;'
script.sh: line 5: `    if [[ $line=="Hi*"]]; then'
```

Any help is very much appreciated ..

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `grep`?

Comment: Spaces around `==` but this is job of `grep`

Comment: and whats the process of determining strings that end with a certain word?

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: As per @Cyrus's suggestion, whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Comment: See [Why should there be a space after open square bracketsand before close square bracket in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9581064/4154375) and [Why equal to operator does not work if it is not surrounded by space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4977367/4154375).

Comment: Using `sh` to run a `bash` script is also an error; see [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: Ok  I got it, thanks @John1024

Answer (score 2):

Simply use grep..like @Poshi and @anubhava said..

No need to use such structure...

1. For detecting  the lines that start with a string :

   ```
   grep "^strt" f.txt
   ```
2. Matching the lines that end with a string:

   ```
   grep "endstr$" f.txt
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if [[ $line=="Hi*"]]; then
```

1. Between `if` and `then`, you provide a list of commands. `[[` is a command, it is not mere syntax. For quick documentations, at a bash prompt, enter `help if` and `help [[`.
2. The shell relies on whitespace to separate commands from arguments. For example, you have to type `cd some_directory`, not `cdsome_directory`
3. The `[[` command requires `]]` to be the *last* argument.  This is the source of the error: the closing double brackets *as a stand-alone argument* were not seen before the semicolon.
4. The `[[` command behaves differently depending on how many arguments it receives. For example, when given a single argument, `[[` will return "success" if that argument is a non-empty string. So you will get different results when $line does **not** start with "Hi":

   ```
   line=foo
   [[ $line=="Hi"* ]]   && echo Y || echo N     # prints Y
   [[ $line == "Hi"* ]] && echo Y || echo N     # prints N
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this..very helpful

Comment: It's useful to get suggestions for better ways to solve your problem, but understanding why the errors occur is very important.

Comment: And for a beginner shell scripter, it's pretty impressive. Do you understand why you need `IFS=''` and `-r` and `|| [[ -n $line ]]` ?

Comment: Hi sir, I wont be lying..I had to take the code from stackoverflow..

Comment: Nothing to be ashamed about. Just try to understand all the parts, and how `while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]` is different from `while read line`

Comment: but as far I understood IFS=' ' is for -"not trimming whitespace"..     -r is to stop interpreting backslashes and the  later part is to not ignore the last linne of the file which might not have a  "\n"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188499/discussion-between-user9185187-and-glenn-jackman).