# Regex string matching with Bash [[ operator

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand regex matching in Bash. Can someone help explain the observations with 4,5 and 6. My understanding is the quote around `$y` should treat it literally, but that does not seem to be the case.

```bash
$ x="aa"
$ y="a*"
$ [[ $x == $y ]] && echo "strings match" #1
strings match
$ [[ $x==$y ]] && echo "strings match" #2
strings match
$ [[ $x=$y ]] && echo "strings match" #3
strings match
$ [[ $x="$y" ]] && echo "strings match" #4
strings match
$ [[ $x=="$y" ]] && echo "strings match" #5
strings match
$ [[ $x == "$y" ]] && echo "strings match" #6
~1$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: So your question is what's the difference between `[[ $x=="$y" ]]` and `[[ $x == "$y" ]]`?

Comment: And ```[[ $x="$y" ]]``` unless it's always the same as ```[[ $x==$y ]]```

Comment: the binary operator for regex match is `=~`. None of the above are regex matches.

Comment: In which case can someone explain the behavior as asked in the question?

Comment: `==` means the same as `=` in condition. `$x` is the same as `"$x"` if variable  `$x`  contains no spaces.

Comment: The difference is that if you give `[[ ]]` only one parameter — such as `$x=="$y"` — then it just tests whether that parameter is non-empty (which  `$x=="$y"` necessarily is), whereas `$x == "$y"` uses the `==` operator.

Comment: See ["Why does the equal to operator not work if it is not surrounded by spaces?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977367/why-does-the-equal-to-operator-not-work-if-it-is-not-surrounded-by-spaces) and ["Bash Script incorrectly matching all strings with regular expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64180576/bash-script-incorrectly-matching-all-strings-with-regular-expression). Also, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at catching common mistakes like leaving out spaces around the operator (though it will not warn about glob vs regex matching).

Comment: @ruakh, the answer you provide is most relevant. The other answers referenced in the subsequent comment are less relevant / irrelavant to my question.

Comment: (1) As mentioned above, the spaces are important around the `==` in `[[ $x == "$y" ]]` so that the `[[` doesn't test for non-zero-length (2) the quotes on the RHS of a `[[ == ]]` or `[[ = ]]` (they're the same in bash) are important for if you want to pattern-match the value of `y` literally (3) `==` is not regex but rather it enables pattern matching, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b (4) Regex operator for `[[` is `=~`, and assigning regex string to a variable is desired in the regex case (some tips for the road)

Comment: It might help you to undertand that ```[``` and ```[[``` are not syntax, they are commands. In the case of ```[``` it is an alias for the command ```test```, that means every component of what you pass to it has to be separated by spaces just like any other command.